# mobile web page control

Tags: mobile, web, user-experience

For client side, I'm using `HTML/CSS/Javascript` and using `PHP` for server side. For input boxes in mobile web, is there any method that I can manipulate mobile keypad?

For example, for the input boxes which takes user phone numbers, I want to open number keypads first on phone screen. Currently, user has to encounter English keypad first (which is default) and then move on to the numbers.

input = "number" is the method, but in my case, iphone works with this, but android does not support this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type = "tel">` can be the method.